# Cannot connect localhost from Linux Guest to Window Host

Tags: linux

I cannot connect via localhost from Linux Guest to the Windows Host. Here is what I have tried so far:

1. VM Network settings: NAT.

   - Port Forwarding: Host Port = Guest Port = 8000
   - Guest IP = 10.0.2.15

   (info from linux `ifconfig inet` configuration).

   I have tried opening 10.0.2.15:8000 or localhost. And when I pinged guest ip from host, it said "request timed out" although guest firewall has been disabled.
2. VM Network settings: Bridged.

   The result was even worse. It disconnected network on guest.

What am I missing here and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to connect to, from where?

Comment: What type of VM system are you using? My experience is that port forwarding is used by a client that is running on the host (or outside of the host) to connect to a server that is running on the guest. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have virtualbox running on Window and when I run an app on the browser of linux guest, I'd like to open it in the browser of the window host also

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps in this link and see if that works for you:
https://plenium.wordpress.com/2018/07/03/virtualbox-network-setup-for-internet-access/

Comment: I followed by adding the 2nd adapter, but when I ran command "ifconfig" in guest, enp0s8 only showed inet6 without inet

Comment: If you dont get an ipv4 address then you need to setup both a NAT and Host-only adapter. Also try to reboot the VM and see if you get ipv4.